# Only one command line option with argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to create a CLI with the argparse module but I'd like to have different commands with different argument requirements, I tried this:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('foo', help='foo help')
parser.add_argument('test', nargs=1, help='test help')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

what I'd like is to be able to run `python test.py foo` and `python test.py test somearg`
but when I run `python test.py foo` I get `error: too few arguments`. Is there a way that the commands could behave like `git status`, `git commit` or `pip install`? or is there a better way to create a CLI in python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you probably want:

http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

With this you can add sub arguments which have their own argument schemes.

Answer (score 15):

[@crodjer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394328/only-one-command-line-option-with-argparse/6394419#6394419) is correct;
to provide an example:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(title='subcommands', 
                                   description='valid subcommands',
                                   help='additional help')
foo_parser = subparsers.add_parser('foo', help='foo help')
bar_parser = subparsers.add_parser('bar', help='bar help')
bar_parser.add_argument('somearg')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

---

Test of different args per subparser:

```
$ python subparsers_example.py bar somearg
Namespace(somearg='somearg')

$ python subparsers_example.py foo
Namespace()

$ python subparsers_example.py foo somearg
usage: argparse_subparsers.py foo [-h]
subparser_example.py foo: error: unrecognized arguments: somearg
```

Help output:

```
$ python subparsers_example.py foo -h
usage: argparse_subparsers.py foo [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

$ python subparsers_example.py bar -h
usage: argparse_subparsers.py bar [-h] somearg

positional arguments:
  somearg

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, argparse arguments consume one value. If you want foo to have different behavior, you'll need to specify it. It looks like you think the default is nargs=0, but it's not.  From the argparse documentation (at http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs):  "If the nargs keyword argument is not provided, the number of args consumed is determined by the action. Generally this means a single command-line arg will be consumed and a single item (not a list) will be produced."

You can either use nargs='?' for foo and give it a default value in case nothing is provided from the command-line, or use a non-default action (perhaps 'store_true'?).